# UICollectionView + custom cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

please help me with custom cell in collection

i have an error:
..this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cell_label..
you can download full project here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1nXU0xmeKg8WTRYRXJVbWdMVlU/view?usp=sharing

i want to show collection with custom cell in modalview

PS: i use xcode 7 beta and swift 2 and separate xib for every view

```
import UIKit
class ModalController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var myCollection: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCell: colywCell!

    var tableData: [String] = ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title="modal W"
        myCollection.dataSource = self
        myCollection.delegate = self

        let nipName=UINib(nibName: "colywCell", bundle:nil)
        myCollection.registerNib(nipName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        self.myCell = myCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colywCell
        self.myCell.Cell_label.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        return self.myCell
    }
 }
```

and custom cell file

```
import UIKit
```

class colywCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var Cell_label: UILabel!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)  {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code in your question. An external link is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

you need to aware of who the *owner* is, and which *class* should be loaded with the nib.

in nutshell, you need to aware of those in your `colywCell.nib`:

## 1a.

make sure that the File's Owner is *not* a custom class.

[image: no file owner]

## 1b.

make sure to *disconnect* every outlet from File's Owner.

[image: remove outlet connection from File's Owner]

## 2a.

make sure that the actual `UICollectionViewCell` *is* your custom class.

[image: proper custom class]

## 2b.

optionally *connect* the outlets to your custom class.

[image: connecting the outlet to the class, not to the owner]

Comment: did all 3 steps, but have same error. ![<a href="http://imgur.com/eecMJGd"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/eecMJGd.png?1" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>]

Comment: your screenshot is not available, and I'm not sure how you did those steps, the project you linked works on my computer properly after those changes.

Comment: http://imgur.com/eecMJGd    i did all3 steps but have same error when i push "show modal" button on a first view after application starts. is it possible to send me full refactored project, wich have not this error and successfully show modal view with custom cells?

Comment: I have updated my answer to make only __2__ obvious steps only, I hope that helps on you to _disconnect_ the outlets as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error, it usually means that you have an **Outlet** set on your view that is not binded to any `IBOutlet` on your Cell.

This happens when you bind a view with some var in your class and then you remove that var and not it's bind on your xib.